# Get Youtube subscriber count for a user

Tags: api, youtube

I need to get the subscriber count/list of a Youtube user, is there any API which allows this. I have tried using

```
http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/[username]
```

but this returns count of subscriptions not subscribers

Comment: This is no longer available with API v3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is subscriberCount in the returned xml , its the actual subscribers count of your channel .