# Youtube channel subscriber count

Tags: php, youtube

I'm trying to pull the count of subscribers for a particular youtube channel. I referred some links on Stackoverflow as well as external sites, came across links like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10859627/get-youtube-subscriber-count-for-a-user). Almost all the links suggested me to use youtube gdata api and pull the count from subscriberCount but the following code

```
$data   = file_get_contents("http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Tollywood/playlists");
$xml    = simplexml_load_string($data);
```

print_r($xml);

returns no such subscriberCount. Is there any other way of getting subscribers count or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this ;)

```
<?php 
$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Tollywood');

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
$stats_data = (array)$xml->children('yt', true)->statistics->attributes();
$stats_data = $stats_data['@attributes'];

/********* OR **********/

$data = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/Tollywood?alt=json');
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$stats_data = $data['entry']['yt$statistics'];

/**********************************************************/

echo 'lastWebAccess = '.$stats_data['lastWebAccess'].'<br />';
echo 'subscriberCount = '.$stats_data['subscriberCount'].'<br />';
echo 'videoWatchCount = '.$stats_data['videoWatchCount'].'<br />';
echo 'viewCount = '.$stats_data['viewCount'].'<br />';
echo 'totalUploadViews = '.$stats_data['totalUploadViews'].'<br />';
?>
```

Comment: This answer no longer works - YouTube API 2.0 has been deprecated. I've added a newer answer for v3.

Answer (score 13):

The YouTube API v2.0 is deprecated.  Here's how to do it with 3.0.  OAuth is not needed.

1) Log in to a Google account and go to https://console.developers.google.com/.  You may have to start a new project.

2) Navigate to `APIs & auth` and go to Public API Access -> Create a New Key

3) Choose the option you need (I used 'browser applications') This will give you an API key.

4) Navigate to your channel in YouTube and look at the URL. The channel ID is here: https://www.youtube.com/channel/YOUR_CHANNEL_ID

5) Use the API key and channel ID to get your result with this query: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=YOUR_CHANNEL_ID&key=YOUR_API_KEY

Great success!

---

Documentation is actually pretty good, but there's a lot of it.  Here's a couple of key links:

Channel information documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests

"Try it" page: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/subscriptions/list#try-it

Comment: Works perfectly for me actually. Edit: I was getting the wrong channel ID. >.>

Comment: perfect! just all i need it!

Answer (score 7):

I could do it with regex for my page , not sure does it work for you or not . check following codes:

```
<?php 
$channel = 'http://youtube.com/user/YOURUSERNAME/';
$t = file_get_contents($channel);
$pattern = '/yt-uix-tooltip" title="(.*)" tabindex/';
preg_match($pattern, $t, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
echo $matches[1][0];
```

Comment: This works!, Thanks! but any idea how to do this when the subscribers reach into 1000 the count becomes "1K" not the whole count ?

Comment: @RhezJovovich What do you mean exactly ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant formatting if the subscribers count is 1200 becomes 1.2K . Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: Anyway just disregard my questions about the formatting, I already find the answer from existing stackoverflow posts. Now, my question is, Is the "$matches[1][0]" value , returns a string or a number? Thanks a lot!

Comment: @RhezJovovich absolutely string, but if you use `intval` function it will returns the number . you can user simple code to do that formatting like `echo ((intval)$matches[1][0]>1000?(intval)$matches[1][0]/1000).'K':(intval)$matches[1][0]`

Comment: @OnlyMAJ this doesn't work for million and billion right?

Comment: @SurajLulla i didn't check tbh , but i believe so .

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php

//this code was written by Abdu ElRhoul
//If you have any questions please contact me at info@oklahomies.com
//My website is http://Oklahomies.com



set_time_limit(0);

function retrieveContent($url){
$file = fopen($url,"rb");
if (!$file)
    return "";
while (feof ($file)===false) {
    $line = fgets ($file, 1024);
    $salida .= $line;
}
fclose($file);
return $salida;
}

{
$content = retrieveContent("https://www.youtube.com/user/rhoula/about");         //replace rhoula with the channel name
$start = strpos($content,'<span class="about-stat"><b>');
$end = strpos($content,'</b>',$start+1);
$output = substr($content,$start,$end-$start);

echo "Number of Subscribers = $output";
}
?>
```

Comment: This isn't really efficient if they update their source

Comment: Nothing is actually efficient if they update their source.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
echo get_subscriber("UCOshmVNmGce3iwozz55hpww");

function get_subscriber($channel,$use = "user") {
    (int) $subs = 0;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            "https://www.youtube.com/".$use."/".$channel."/about?disable_polymer=1");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           0 ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://www.youtube.com/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:59.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/59.0');
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    $R = curl_getinfo($ch);
    if($R["http_code"] == 200) {
        $pattern = '/yt-uix-tooltip" title="(.*)" tabindex/';
        preg_match($pattern, $result, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
        $subs = intval(str_replace(',','',$matches[1][0]));
    }
    if($subs == 0 && $use == "user") return get_subscriber($channel,"channel");
    return $subs;
}
```