# fetch Youtube subscribers count in PHP

Tags: php, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to fetch the youtube suscriber count in PHP.
I tried using

```
function get_yt_subs($username) { 

$xmlData = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/' . strtolower($username)); 
$xmlData = str_replace('yt:', 'yt', $xmlData); 

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlData); 

$subs = $xml->ytstatistics['subscriberCount']; 

return($subs); 

}
```

and

```
$youtube_url = file_get_contents( 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googlechrome'; 
$youtube_url = str_replace( 'yt:', 'yt', $youtube_url ); 
$youtube_data = $youtube_url->ytstatistics['subscriberCount'];
```

both these methods, but it does not work. It's showing error
file_get_contents(http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googlechrome): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 410 Gone

Comment: possible duplicate of [Youtube channel subscriber count](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13871817/youtube-channel-subscriber-count)

Comment: But how het rid of file_get_contents() error?

Comment: The call you are making is to v2 of the API which has been deprecated. You need to call the equivalent v3 API service. For a specific channel you can use: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list and specify `part` as `statistics`